# OpenCL Multi-Device CommandQueue Concurrency Issue (NVIDIA)

Tags: concurrency, opencl, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

I'm having issues executing clEnqueue* commands concurrently for different devices. Page 25 of the [OpenCL 1.1 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.1.pdf) says

> It is possible to associ ate multiple queues with a single context. 
>   These queues run concurrently  and independently with no explicit
>   mechanisms within OpenCL to synchronize between them.

But, as per my [post here](https://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/11619-NVIDIA-Multi-Device-Command-Queue-Concurrency-Issue), this is blatantly not the case. I have a repository I'm creating to showcase the feature set of OpenCL. I'm building from basics up to some more complicated examples. I had to halt my progress early because I noticed that, in single-threaded host software using multiple commandqueues (one per device), there seemed to be some unexplained blocking which eliminated all concurrency. More details are presented [here](https://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/11619-NVIDIA-Multi-Device-Command-Queue-Concurrency-Issue), but the gist is that I am seeing this:

[image]

when I would expect to be seeing something like this:

[image]

Apparently I have been doing OpenCL wrong for all this time... Ideally, I would like to see someone

- point out that I'm doing something wrong
- run my software successfully on their machine (pointing to issues in my environment)
- confirm that this is a bug with the NVIDIA OpenCL 1.1 implementation and/or nvidia-346 driver's version of libOpenCL.so

You can pull my software from [here](https://github.com/stevenovakov/learnOpenCL), the instructions for running/compiling are in the README. **Please try to stay in the ``simple_events" branch at the moment, as it is how I would write a typical OpenCL program.** Cheers.